# Spring integation parallel split

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have code like this.
Is it possible to control ordering of first split?

```
` @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    return executor;
  }


  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow firstFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("firstChannel")
        .split()
        .channel("inputChannel")
        .get();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow inputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
        .channel(MessageChannels.executor(taskExecutor()))
        .split()
        .handle(this::mapping)
        .aggregate()
        .channel("aggregateChannel")
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow aggregateFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("aggregateChannel")
        .aggregate()
        .get();
  }`
```

I want to have async handling of method "mapping", but to start handling second message from first split and sending to inputChannel only when first one will appear in aggregateChannel

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to split sequentially an original message, but process their items in parallel? So, you would start processing the next one only when the first one is fully processed, even if its items was processed in parallel?

Comment: Yes, that's what i would like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is a unit test for possible solution:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
public class So75547720Tests {

    @Autowired
    BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Test
    void sequentialSplitButSubSplitParallel() {
        List<String> firstList = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4");
        List<String> secondList = List.of("5", "6", "7", "8");
        List<List<String>> testData = List.of(firstList, secondList);

        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
        messagingTemplate.setBeanFactory(this.beanFactory);

        List<List<String>> result = messagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("firstChannel", testData, List.class);
        assertThat(result).isNotNull().hasSize(2);
        assertThat(result.get(0)).hasSameElementsAs(firstList);
        assertThat(result.get(1)).hasSameElementsAs(secondList);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
            return executor;
        }


        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow firstFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlow.from("firstChannel")
                    .split()
                    .channel("inputChannel")
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow inputFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlow.from("inputChannel")
                    .gateway(subFlow -> subFlow
                            .split()
                            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(taskExecutor()))
                            .handle(this::mapping)
                            .aggregate())
                    .channel("aggregateChannel")
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow aggregateFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlow.from("aggregateChannel")
                    .aggregate()
                    .get();
        }

        private String mapping(String payload, Map<String, ?> headers) {
            System.out.println("Handling thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " for: " + payload);
            return payload.toUpperCase();
        }

    }

}
```

The first `split()` emits items sequentially into that `inputChannel`.
Then we use a `gateway` for sub-flow. This gateway will wait for a reply to push it forward for the next `aggregateChannel`. The interesting part is indeed in that sub-flow where we use a second splitter which does emit items in parallel according to an `Executor` channel. An inner aggregator won't emit until it gathers all the items for current split. And only after that we go for the next item from a top level split.

The result of the test might be like this:

```
Handling thread: taskExecutor-2 for: 2
Handling thread: taskExecutor-1 for: 1
Handling thread: taskExecutor-3 for: 3
Handling thread: taskExecutor-4 for: 4
Handling thread: taskExecutor-2 for: 6
Handling thread: taskExecutor-5 for: 5
Handling thread: taskExecutor-3 for: 7
Handling thread: taskExecutor-1 for: 8
[[2, 3, 1, 4], [6, 5, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! And maybe you could answer, is it possible to keep this architecture, but create a new ThreadPoolExecutor each time depending on the values ​​that would be in the headers. 
For example, set type in headers. Create strategies for certain processes, where to specify the number of threads and timeout for a strategy with a given type. 
And get these values ​​from the strategy for creating ThreadPoolExecutor . 
But I can't figure out how it's possible to pass these values ​​to .channel(MessageChannels.executor()

Comment: No, it is not possible. All the bean must be created at startup phase, so you cannot modify the channel at runtime. It is possible to play with dynamic flow, but that is fully different story: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows